# Accuracy either 0 or 1 in CNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I've taken this CNN example (https://github.com/dennybritz/cnn-text-classification-tf) which classifies movie reviews as positive or negative and am trying to classify an array of arrays instead of an array of integers. I've taken the example and adjusted it to classify more input data per class. The problem is that in my version it only classifies one of 2 classes with an accuracy of 1.0, the other classification has an accuracy of 0.0. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

As input, the example originally had a list of vectors as X and a corresponding list of classification as Y:

input_x in original example (17 integers per classification):

```
    [1', 2', 3', 4', 5', 6', 7', 8', 0', 0', 0', 0', 0', 0', 0', 0', 0'],
    [1', 2', 23', 49', 58', 64', 27', 82', 33', 0', 0', 0', 0', 0', 0', 0', 0']
```

input_y in original example:

```
    [1,0], #this was a negative movie review
    [0,1]  #this was a positive movie review
```

The new input (after my adjustments) consists of an array of around 713 arrays with 60 floats like this:

input_x in my version (713 arrays of 60 floats per classification):

```
    [0.86099077150603431, 0.129, 0.12933333333333333, 0.12966666666666668, 0.13, 0.13033333333333333, 0.13066666666666665, 0.124, 0.083333333333333329, 0.13100000000000001, 0.083333333333333329, 0.13133333333333333, 0.017999999999999999, 0.13166666666666665, 0.13200000000000001, 0.13233333333333333, 0.13266666666666665, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.86099080964707053, 0.5403, 0.54000000000000004]
    [0.8609932408012354, 0.59399999999999997, 0.125, 0.59433333333333338, 0.024666666666666667, 0.53300000000000003, 0.59466666666666668, 0.59499999999999997, 0.59533333333333338, 0.0096666666666666672, 0.29266666666666669, 0.59433333333333338, 0.14733333333333334, 0.0089999999999999993, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.86099298342284247, 0.54069999999999996, 0.54044999999999999]
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.86099227073780937, 0.54059999999999997, 0.54044999999999999]
```

input_y in my version:

```
    [1,0] #one classification for an entire batch of 713 arrays of 60 floats
```

When training with only 12 datasets with 12 corresponding classifications (1 classification per batch), the accuracy and loss develops as follows:

[Accuracy graph to 20 batches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kxhJ.png)

What stands out is that once the model seems trained, the accuracy per batch is either 0.0 or 1.0. It classifies [0,1] with an accuracy of 1, while is classifies [1,0] with 0.0 accuracy. What could be the problem here? I've tried tweaking all parameters, like learning rate and number of filters/convolution layers. (The learning rate seems to work best around 0.01 while the number of filters_sizes seem to work best as follows: 3,4,5,6)

Here an early batch and a mature batch. Note the difference in accuracy.

```
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    ------------------------------Batch 5----------------------------
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    ---- Training averages per batch: loss: 5.57, accuracy:0.79 ---

    2017-06-26T11:17:54.625416: step 49, loss 0.60, acc 0.83 - X: 713/670Y:[0 1]
    2017-06-26T11:18:01.825974: step 50, loss 0.55, acc 0.99 - X: 712/422Y:[0 1]
    2017-06-26T11:18:08.960984: step 51, loss 11.40, acc 0.01 - X: 713/578Y:[1 0]
    2017-06-26T11:18:15.795436: step 52, loss 2.77, acc 0.29 - X: 712/477Y:[0 1]
    2017-06-26T11:18:22.635306: step 53, loss 1.05, acc 0.57 - X: 713/464Y:[1 0]
    2017-06-26T11:18:29.465720: step 54, loss 3.22, acc 0.19 - X: 712/447Y:[0 1]
    2017-06-26T11:18:36.271625: step 55, loss 0.97, acc 0.62 - X: 713/581Y:[0 1]
    2017-06-26T11:18:43.075573: step 56, loss 0.58, acc 0.92 - X: 712/475Y:[0 1]
    2017-06-26T11:18:49.843150: step 57, loss 0.56, acc 0.99 - X: 712/618Y:[0 1]
    2017-06-26T11:18:56.643769: step 58, loss 0.56, acc 1.00 - X: 712/683Y:[0 1]
    2017-06-26T11:19:03.465074: step 59, loss 0.56, acc 1.00 - X: 713/464Y:[0 1]
    2017-06-26T11:19:10.300384: step 60, loss 0.56, acc 1.00 - X: 713/636Y:[0 1]
```

While later in the training procedure, the accuracy of each batch is either 0.0 or 1.0, Which causes the grand total accuracy to average out to 0.83.

```
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    ------------------------------Batch 9----------------------------
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    ---- Training averages per batch: loss: 1.09, accuracy:0.83 ---

    2017-06-26T11:23:30.285332: step 97, loss 0.99, acc 1.00 - X: 713/670Y:[0 1]
    2017-06-26T11:23:37.453523: step 98, loss 1.31, acc 0.00 - X: 713/464Y:[1 0]
    2017-06-26T11:23:44.365591: step 99, loss 1.31, acc 0.00 - X: 713/578Y:[1 0]
    2017-06-26T11:23:51.450830: step 100, loss 0.96, acc 1.00 - X: 712/475Y:[0 1]
    2017-06-26T11:23:58.571929: step 101, loss 0.96, acc 1.00 - X: 713/464Y:[0 1]
    2017-06-26T11:24:05.490809: step 102, loss 0.95, acc 1.00 - X: 712/618Y:[0 1]
    2017-06-26T11:24:12.307687: step 103, loss 0.95, acc 1.00 - X: 712/683Y:[0 1]
    2017-06-26T11:24:19.114356: step 104, loss 0.94, acc 1.00 - X: 713/581Y:[0 1]
    2017-06-26T11:24:26.267000: step 105, loss 0.93, acc 1.00 - X: 712/422Y:[0 1]
    2017-06-26T11:24:33.391093: step 106, loss 0.92, acc 1.00 - X: 712/447Y:[0 1]
    2017-06-26T11:24:40.632168: step 107, loss 0.92, acc 1.00 - X: 713/636Y:[0 1]
    2017-06-26T11:24:47.740179: step 108, loss 0.91, acc 1.00 - X: 712/477Y:[0 1]
```

I can post code if I need to. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What's your batch size? Usually, accuracy that jumps between 0 and 1 means that you're measuring small batches that don't capture the entire variability of the training/validation set. Try measuring it on the whole train/validation set and see if things start making sense

Comment: The issue i think is the class imbalance in your training set. First Try downsampling your positive set and check the accuracies.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! I've tried a new small dataset with equally balanced classes (50 / 50). Unfortunatly the accuracy of individual batches remained 1.0 or 0.0, averaging the total accuracy to about .5. @nessuno This could be the problem. My batch size is 1 because of a dimensionality issue, If I increase the batch size a valueerror pops up which i wasn't able to fix before: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. (in train_step() on line _, step, summaries, loss, accuracy = sess.run([train_op, global_step, train_summary_op, cnn.loss, cnn.accuracy],  feed_dict)).

Comment: Well, the error is from python and it's pretty clear. You're setting an array element with a sequence. Show the code

Comment: @nessuno the error is from within the tensorflow library (session.py). Stacktrace here:  File "train.py", line 398, in train_step
    _, step, summaries, loss, accuracy = sess.run([train_op, global_step, train_summary_op, cnn.loss, cnn.accuracy],  feed_dict)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 766, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 937, in _run
    np_val = np.asarray(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)

Comment: The subfeed_val which is passed to np.asarray has the following structure: [[[0.8523, 0.0003, ......],[0.852, 0.0003, ......]]]. This is my input_x array which is fed straight into the sess.run call. Any idea's?

Comment: I can't help you in this way, understanding a stacktrace without formatting and without seeing any code is a real pain

Comment: @nessuno ok thank you, I am on the right track thanks to your comment!